# How do you insert a new record or update an existing if id already exists with inner join?

Tags: mysql

The goal is to insert a new record or update an existing if the id column exists. The ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE function seems to be a good fit but the problem I have is I want to make sure that the ID matches an ID in another table. This is for permissions. An example is:

```
INSERT INTO `testtable` (`id`, `user_id`, `order`, `active`)
VALUES
   (1, 24, 3, 0),
   (2, 24, 1, 1),
   (NULL, 24, 2, 0) AS newupdate
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   order = newupdate.order,
   active = newupdate.active
```

This works but I want to add a check where the testtable.user_id from above matches users.id from another table. I've been using this SELECT statement:

```
SELECT testtable.id, testtable.order, testtable.active
FROM testtable
INNER JOIN users on testtable.user_id = users.id
WHERE users.username = bob
```

So I can't figure out how to utilize the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with an INNER JOIN or perhaps I'm going about this all the wrong way. I search Stackoverflow and saw some suggestions to use a SELECT statement with the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but I don't understand how that passes the values. Anyway, is this possible? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I was able to get it working but it seems like there should be an easier/better way? Anyone have any other suggestions? This example below I'm inserting a row with id 24 which exists so the update runs and then I'm inserting a row with id NULL so it gets inserted as is.

```
INSERT INTO `testtable` (`id`, `user_id`, `order`, `active`)
SELECT `id`, `user_id`, `order`, `active`
FROM (SELECT
     24 AS id,
     (SELECT user_id FROM testtable INNER JOIN users on testtable.user_id = users.id WHERE users.username = 'bob' LIMIT 1) AS user_id,
     6 AS order,
     1 AS active
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
     NULL AS id,
     (SELECT user_id FROM testtable INNER JOIN users on testtable.user_id = users.id WHERE users.username = 'bob' LIMIT 1) AS user_id,
     7 AS order,
     1 AS active
     )
AS newtable
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
order = newtable.order,
active = newtable.active
```

Comment: Why not have a foreign key on testable(user_id) referencing users ?

Comment: Use INSERT .. SELECT, not INSERT .. VALUES.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My specific use case has a web based front end and I'm trying to prevent anyone from inspecting (ex. developer tools in chrome) the table that contains the testtable data and modifying specifically the user_id value. If I understand correctly a foreign key will just make sure the value exists in the foreign key table correct? If so, this wouldn't necessarily prevent someone from altering the UPSERT statement.

Comment: @Akina Thank you for your response. I've seen that suggestion but I don't understand how the values are passed along to the insert part of the statement? In my example provided VALUES (1, 24, 3, 0), (2, 24, 1, 1)... is what I don't understand how to insert if using the INSERT .. SELECT as you suggested.

Comment: ```INSERT INTO `testtable` (`id`, `user_id`, `order`, `active`) SELECT `id`, `user_id`, `order`, `active` FROM (SELECT 1, 24, 3, 0 UNION ALL SELECT 2, 24, 1, 1) AS data_source (`id`, `user_id`, `order`, `active`) JOIN users  ... WHERE ...```.

Comment: @Akina Thanks Akina for the code sample but my statement as I wrote it isn't working. See below. 
INSERT INTO testtable (id, user_id, order, active) 
SELECT id, user_id, order, active 
FROM (SELECT 1, 24, 1, 0 
UNION ALL SELECT 21, 24, 5, 1) AS newupdate (id, user_id, order, active) 
INNER JOIN users on testtable.user_id = users.id 
WHERE testtable.id = 24 
AND users.username = 'bob' 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
order = newupdate.order, active = newupdate.active, ringfor = newupdate.ringfor

Comment: The data table alias is `newupdate`, not `testtable`. So ```.. INNER JOIN users on newupdate.user_id = users.id ..```. In WHERE ```.. testtable.id = 24 ..``` must be edited too - but I don't understand this condition, it does not match the data to be inserted...

Comment: If you look at my original post, specifically the SELECT statement, that might help understand the condition. I did add a bit more to the WHERE statement but otherwise it's mainly the same.

Comment: @Akina I updated my post with updated code that works but it seems a bit clunky especially if I have many rows I want to update/insert at once. My example code has just two rows.

Comment: Please provide: source data for tables `testtable` and `users` ( as INSERT INTO + CREATE TABLE scripts, 5-7 rows per table), the data to be inserted (already present in 1st query) and desired final state for `testtable`. PS. Does the foreign key relation between the tables exists?

Comment: *This works but I want to add a check where the `testtable.user_id` from above matches `users.id` from another table.* It is clear that if the cheching result is positive then the row is inserted... but what if there is no matched row? Do not insert? insert according row into `users` and insert specified row? something else?

Answer (score 0):

Here we have a foreign key to users and a trigger to block changing `user_id`.

> ```
> create table users(
>   id int primary key,
>   user varchar(25));
> insert into users values
> (12,'Andrew'),
> (24,'Bernard');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> create table testtable (
>   id int ,
>   user_id int unique,
>   order_ int,
>   active int,
>   foreign key fk_user_id (user_id)
>     references users(id));
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `testtable` (`id`, `user_id`, `order_`, `active`)
> VALUES
>    (1, 24, 3, 0),
>    (2, 24, 1, 1),
>    (NULL, 24, 2, 0) AS newupdate
> ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
>    order_ = newupdate.order_,
>    active = newupdate.active
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> /*delimiter $$ */
>
>  create trigger user_id_update
>  before update on testtable
>
>  for each row
>  begin
>      if (old.user_id <>new.user_id) then
>     signal SQLSTATE VALUE '45000' 
>       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'user_id change forbidden';
>   end if ;
> end ;
>
> /* delimiter ; */
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from testtable;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | user_id | order_ | active
> -: | ------: | -----: | -----:
>  1 |      24 |      2 |      0
> ```

> ```
> update testtable
> set user_id = 12 where user_id = 24;
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id change forbidden
> ```

> ```
> select * from testtable;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | user_id | order_ | active
> -: | ------: | -----: | -----:
>  1 |      24 |      2 |      0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a929caf0c04d34a5f736433eb184e19d)*